# шаблон шаблона класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть кусок кода взят из книги Джосатиса "Шаблоны С++" 2003 года.

```
template <typename T, template <typename ELEM> class C = std::vector>
struct B
{
  C<T> c;
};
```

Почему компилятор ругается на `std::vector` типа шаблон класса несовместим с параметр шаблона `template C`?

1. Использую MS VisualStudio 2022
2. Компилятор Стандарт ISO C++14 (/std:c++14)
3. Версия SDK 10.0.22621.0

Comment: `template <typename T, template <typename ELEM> class C = std::vector>` Что значит эта строка? Что вы хотите тут делать?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы пытались повторить код из раздела 5.7 "Шаблонов С++" Вандевурда? :) В VC++ 2022 отлично работает... Какой именно у вас компилятор и с какими ключиками?

Comment: GCC тоже: https://godbolt.org/z/EbMEo9j93

Comment: @Harry все верно! Стоит студия 2022 компилятор выбран 14. Если поставить 17 то все компилируется. Я бы и внимания не обратил на это, но есть книга Вандервуда 2003 года, там таже конструкция описана и уж явно у него все компилировалось. Ключи : `/JMC /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++14 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column `

Comment: Там же четко говорится, что для контейнера (там рассмотрен дек) это не сработает, поскольку у него два шаблонных параметра. В книге 2003 года — без упоминания стандарта... *Проблема заключается в том, что шаблонный аргумент шаблона должен представлять собой шаблон с параметрами, **точно** соответствующими параметрам шаблонного параметра шаблона, который этот аргумент замещает. Значения по умолчанию для шаблонных аргументов шаблона во внимание не принимаются, так что нельзя добиться точного соответствия, просто опустив аргументы, которые имеют значения по умолчанию.*

Comment: Что интересно, Clang компилирует это только с `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Comment: @Harry c deque так же не работает. У vector и deque два параметра. У обоих. 
```_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty, class _Alloc = allocator<_Ty>>
class deque {```

Comment: Стоит добавить текст ошибки в вопрос. Через ссылку [edit]

Comment: @Fynjisx А где я написал, что работает?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас компилятор не поддерживает (или вы ему не разрешили) стандарт C++17.

Попробуйте пояснить ему, что у вас контейнер с двумя шаблонными параметрами:

```
template <typename T, 
          template <typename E, 
                    typename=std::allocator<E>> 
          class C = std::vector>
struct B
....
```

Comment: Еще можно просто `template <typename...> class C = std::vector`.

Comment: @Harry вот так как Вы написали работает, но я не понял, что ВЫ сделали. Зачем еще прописывать это аллокатор<E>? Извините но изучаю шаблоны поэтому вязну пока конкретно

Comment: Потому что до С++17 требовалось **точное** соответствие. А тот же шаблон `vector` мы, конечно, обычно пишем как `vector<int>`,но там есть и второй шаблонный параметр — аллокатор. Вот и надо передать ему **два** параметра.